# Конвертер Markdown -> Latex C++ regex

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, std-regex

Пишу C++ программу для конвертации Markdown в Latex.
У меня возникла проблема при конвертировании блоков кода, в Latex я хотел использовать пакет listings.

В MD код выделяется таким образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот собственно сам код:

````
string replace_code_area(string MD) {
    regex line("```(.*?)\n([.\n]*?)```");

    string tex = regex_replace(MD, line, "\\lstset{language=$1}\n\\begin{lstlisting}$2\\end{lstlisting}");

    if (tex != MD) {
        ::code_area_found = true;
    }

    return tex;
}
````

При запуске с такими исходными данными:

````
# Problem in regex

__First Bold__, __Second Bold__
_First Italic_, _Second Italic_

***Ha Ha*** *I like***This language**

---

\\```
a = 5
b = 7
a, b = b, a
\\```

``Not code``
````

Выдаёт вот такой результат

````
\documentclass{article} 
 \begin{document} 
\Huge  Problem in regex

\textbf{First Bold}, \textbf{Second Bold}
\textit{First Italic}, \textit{Second Italic}

\textit{\textbf{Ha Ha}} \textit{I like}\textbf{This language}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\\```Python
a = 5
b = 7
a, b = b, a
\\```

``Not code``


\end{document}
````

Т.е блок кода не изменяется в принципе. Функция `replace_code_area` вызывается гарантированно, я добавил cout после объявления регулярного выражения, и оно действительно выводило текст в консоль.

**В коде `*3 (3 знака`) заменено на //``` что бы сайт не воспринимал это как часть блока кода.**

Comment: вместо точки пытался использовать \d\D но всё равно не помогает.

Comment: Где вы видите последовательности точек и знаков перевода на новую строку? `[.\n]*` находит последовательности 0 и более точек и знаков перевода на новую строку. Что вы делаете?

Comment: Вместо точки я пытался использовать \d\D - т.е. любой символ, но всё равно не помогало

Comment: . -любой символ кроме первода строки.

Comment: `.` находит любой символ, кроме перевода строки. `[.]` находит только символ `.`. Может, вам нужен ``regex line("```(.*)\n([\\s\\S]*?)```")``?